# Building HTML using loops in JS

Tags: javascript

Afternoon all, I am trying to build some HTML elements in JS through a loop within which I have another loop.  I have written the HTML so I know what I  want, so I have now tried to translate it into the JS.

The HTML I want to build (this will be a 3x3 grid):

```
<div class="grid">
    <div class="square-row d-flex flex-row">
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="square-row d-flex flex-row">
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="square-row d-flex flex-row">
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the JS code I have written (sorry for the poor formating (my first Stackoverflow post and I cannot get it to behave):

```
function generateGrid(requirement) {
  let grid = `
<div class="grid">
`;
  if (requirement) {
for (let i = 0; i < gridSize; i++) {
  let gridRow = `
    <div class="square-row d-flex flex-row">
    `;
    for (let s = 0; s < gridSize; s++) {
      let square = `
        <div class="square squares" id="${i}"></div>
        `;
      gridRow += square;
    }
  gridRow +=`
    </div>
  `;
}
} else {
for (let i = 0; i < gridSize; i++) {
  let gridRow = `
    <div class="square-row d-flex flex-row">
    `;
    for (let x = 0; x < gridSize; x++) {
      let square =`
        <div class="square squares" id="square${i}" onclick="addColour(${i})"></div>
        `;
      gridRow += square;
    }
  gridRow +=`
    </div>
  `;
}
  }
      grid += `
 </div>
`;

return grid;
}
```

I end up with this when I run it:

```
<div class="grid">

</div>
```

I have used the keyword 'debugger' in the middle of the loop and it is moving through it.  gridSize is the value of 3, so the outer loop should run three times with the inner loop also running three times for each run of the outer.

Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you're redeclaring `gridRow` each time through the loop. Move the declaration up a level

Comment: Actually, does that variable even get used to append to the grid anywhere?

Comment: Thankyou for your response; once you pointed my error out it was very obvious!  That variable does not get used again outside of that function.

Comment: Onca again - thanks a lot Brian; hair was nearly lost to this one!

Answer (score 0):

Im not 100% sure exactly what you meant but it seems your issue is a simple mistake of forgetting to add the gridRow to the grid.

```js
let gridSize = 3

function generateGrid(requirement) {
    let grid = `<div class="grid">\n`;
    if (requirement) {
        for (let i = 0; i < gridSize; i++) {
            let gridRow = `\t<div class="square-row d-flex flex-row">\n`;
            for (let s = 0; s < gridSize; s++) {
                let square = `\t\t<div class="square squares" id="square${i}" onclick="addColour(${i})"></div>\n`
                if (requirement) {
                    square = `\t\t<div class="square squares" id="${i}"></div>\n`;
                }
                gridRow += square;
            }
            gridRow += `\t</div>\n`;
            grid += gridRow; // this line
        }
    }
    grid += `</div>\n`;

    return grid;
}

console.log(generateGrid(true))
```

Comment: Hi Eric - sorry I am trying to get my head around this interface; I believe you posted the corrected code above.  Thank you for your time on this.